# How can I use my custom ConfigurationProperties in custom WebAuthenticationDetails?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring 4.3.x, I have a custom class, call it MyWebAuthenticationDetails that extends WebAuthenticationDetails. I need to use properties in that class that are defined in application.properties. I get those properties via a custom class, called AuthenticationProperties, that uses @ConfigurationProperties. Normally I would autowire in AuthenticationProperties on the class constructor, but that is not possible for MyWebAuthenticationDetails. How can I access properties from within my extension of WebAuthenticationDetails?

Comment: Add your relevant code to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `MyWebAuthenticationDetails` custom details object will be constructed through an `AuthenticationDetailsSource` bean (which you should have already declared), you can access the `AuthenticationProperties` as an injected bean thus you will have all your properties accessible.

A simple *Java* configuration template would be as follows (note that this is not a full functional configuration and aims only to highlight the important configuration entries):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authenticationDetailsSource(myAuthenticationDetailsSource())/* and all the missiong HTTP configuration*/;
    }

    @Bean
    private AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, MyWebAuthenticationDetails> myAuthenticationDetailsSource() {
        return new MyAuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, MyWebAuthenticationDetails>();
    }

    private final class MyAuthenticationDetailsSource extends AuthenticationDetailsSourceImpl<HttpServletRequest, MyWebAuthenticationDetails> {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties;

        @Override
        public MyWebAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return new MyWebAuthenticationDetails(request, this.authenticationProperties);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot this gets created through the AuthenticationDetailsSource impl. Thank you!